# Can we hasten Moshiach's coming through the mitzvah of ואהבת לרעך כמוך?

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, song-poetry, love, love-thy-neighbor

In Jewish singer Meilech Kohn's song, "[Veuhavtu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmdE7Ne6o7Y)", he expresses an interesting thought in the lyrics:

> .יעדער איינער דאווענט און בעט און מ'ווארט פאר משיח, ער וועט נאר קומען ווען מיר פארטראגן זיך

"Everyone prays and begs and waits for Moshiach; he will only come when we all get along."

This is a nice idea, however, I've never heard it expressed in any sources. Is there a source for this idea, that through the mitzvah of ואהבת לרעך כמוך we can merit Moshiach?

<sup>By the way, an a capella version of the song can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wq0ChEGkdFs) from Ari Goldwag.</sup>

Comment: Aren't there numerous *drashim* (I think Chafetz Chaim, most notably) that stated that since the 2nd Bet Hamikdash was destroyed b/c of *Sinat Chinam* then the 3rd Bet Hamidash would be hastened via *Ahavat Chinam*? Isn't that the best "proof"?

Comment: here's it is quoted in the name of HaRav Kook:  https://www.thejc.com/judaism/jewish-words/sinat-chinam-1.8105 . Here it is quoted in the name of the Chofetz Chaim: http://1daastorah.blogspot.com/2013/07/ahavas-chinam-key-to-geulah-key-to-good.html

Comment: Lubavitcher Rebbe said it a lot at public speeches. "hastened via ahavas chinam ; being oppositie of sinas chinam which therefore has the opposite effect of destruction."

Comment: Logically, the main "goal" of Mashiach is to bring about unity. Physical unity by the gathering of people to one place - land of Israel, and spiritual unity by having everyone recognize G-d. When you consider this, wouldn't the lack of hatred and petty / baseless disputes  fit into the unity concept, as well. If we prepare for that, in advance, it seems to me that a large part of Mashiach's "job" would already be done.

Comment: i believe every mitzva hastens the coming of Moshiach

Comment: Ezra, while not direct, think of what the 2nd to last Pasuk of Malachi (the Shabbat Hagadol Haftara) says. When Eliyahu (a sign of Mashiach) comes, he will return the hearts of the fathers unto the sons and the sons toward the fathers. I don't think this is limited to just individual families. It seems to be a metaphor to the concept that people as a whole will end all disputes.

Comment: Somewhat related to this concept - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZW-NKGXFGg Near the end of the video, the rabbi cites the very pasuk that I mentioned. I think you'll enjoy the rest of the video, too.

Comment: @m.r. You are correct. But, remember that Hillel (in a sense) and Rav Akiva stated that this mitzvah alone is the basis of the Torah; all else is commentary. Ahah! That implies that every other mitzvah is based on unity and love for our fellow. Preparing for Mashiach means that we need to prepare ourselves for the concept and understanding of unity and, specifically, this single mitzvah, alone.

Comment: @DanF I love Rabbi Locks and I've seen the video before. All of his videos are great

Comment: Something I must add here - The Gemara in Yoma mentions how the Beis HaMikdash Sheini was destroyed because of sinas chinam. What is the opposite of sinas chinam - love. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This idea can be found in [Medrash Tanchuma, Nitzavim 1:](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma,_Nitzavim.1.1?with=all&lang=bi)

> וְכֵן אַתְּ מוֹצֵא שֶׁאֵין יִשְׂרָאֵל נִגְאֲלִין עַד שֶׁיִּהְיוּ כֻּלָּן אֲגֻדָּה אַחַת, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: בַּיָּמִים הָהֵמָּה וּבָעֵת הַהִיא נְאֻם ה' יָבֹאוּ בְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וּבְנֵי יְהוּדָה יַחְדָּו וְגוֹ' ([ירמיה נ, ד](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.50.4?with=all&lang=bi)). כְּשֶׁהֵן אֲגוּדִים, מְקַבְּלִין פְּנֵי שְׁכִינָה
>
> Yisroel will not be redeemed until they will all be one group, as it says: "In those days and at that time—declares the LORD—the people of Israel together with the people of Judah shall come, etc." [(Yirmiya 50:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.50.4?with=all&lang=bi)) When they are a group, they receive the face of the shchina

Comment: Another clear, fast, and well-sourced answer!

Comment: Very nice; kol hakavod! To other users: I would like to hear other sources as well.