# How to reduce Sinas Chinam

Tags: beis-hamikdash, messiah

Sinas Chinam (baseless hatred) is often given as the reason why Moshiach hasn't come and we don't have the 3rd Beis HaMikdash (Holy Temple).  Are there any sources for what we can do on a personal level and a communal level to help reduce Sinas Chinam and inspire others to follow suit?

Surely this is something we should all be prioritising.

Comment: I've usually seen it given as a reason the second temple was destroyed, not what you said.

Comment: @DoubleAA That _is_ true, however by extension it could be argued the only way to rectify that error is to have _ahavas yisroel_, see my question and the answer to it here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91403/can-we-hasten-moshiachs-coming-through-the-mitzvah-of-%d7%95%d7%90%d7%94%d7%91%d7%aa-%d7%9c%d7%a8%d7%a2%d7%9a-%d7%9b%d7%9e%d7%95%d7%9a

Comment: @ezra that's not a valid extension. maybe we did that already but are stuck on something else.

Comment: @DoubleAA Possibly. I think to answer that question we might look into why the Second Beis Hamikdash was built...Since the First was destroyed because of avodo zaro, then _maybe_ it was rebuilt because Bnei Yisroel stopped worshiping idols... If that's true then I think it's alright to assume the way to get the Third Beis Hamikdash built is to have more ahavas yisroel to make up for the sinas chinam we had before

Answer (score 5):

I recommend the Aleph Beta video ["Sinat Chinam: The Great Tisha B'Av Crime:
What Is Baseless Hatred, Anyway?"](https://www.alephbeta.org/playlist/baseless-hatred-sinat-chinam). In it, [R' David Fohrman](https://www.alephbeta.org/faq) analyzes the Talmud's core story of baseless hatred - ["Kamtza / bar Kamtza"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamsa_and_Bar_Kamsa) and derives the lesson that "baseless hatred" means irrationally expressing rage at someone whom you have reason to be somewhat angry at, but not enraged. He advises cultivating a practice of checking yourself when you're enraged to determine whether you really ought to be *that* angry at *that* target.

Answer (score 3):

Be prompt in intervening when someone does something wrong is what's implied by the following:

-What is “senseless hatred”?

> Rashi on Shabbat 32b:  It is hatred of people who have not committed any action justifying the hatred.

-When does the hatred make sense?

> Pesachim 113b:  You may bear ill will towards someone if you *witnessed* him engaging in a forbidden act.
>
> Bava Metzia 32b: But you must assist him *before* assisting those you love [so that ill will does not turn to hatred.]
>
> Sanhedrin 27b:  A hater [sone] is someone who does not speak to his fellow for 3 days because of enmity.

When the Talmud says: "The Temple was destroyed because of senseless hatred", the common interpretation is that Jewish factions were fighting among themselves and made it easier for the Romans to win the war.  But elsewhere, the Talmud says that the senseless hatred was a lot more focused: The war happened because of a strange backwater chain of events that wouldn't even have made the newspapers. [See Gittin 55b-56a and Lamentations Rabbah 4:3]

If you read the story, it's clear the host did not properly engage Bar Kamtza (who accepted the invitation because he thought it was an olive branch). There is the senseless hatred. Had he engaged him and cleared the misunderstanding as Bava Metzia 32b (above) says, that would have been the only proper way to proceed.